Rates and Transit Times API is giving 400 Bad Request error if I change the account number using codeigniter 4
I am working with program where we need to fetch details from FedEx Rates and Transit API, the API works fine with the account number which is linked to API project in developers portal but once I try to change another account number the API returns error:

file_get_contents(https://apis.fedex.com/rate/v1/rates/quotes): Failed
to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

can't find the enough information on API documentation and in search.
Question 1: I want to confirm is there any restriction on API end that we can fetch data from only those accounts which are linked? or we need to change our parameter?
Question 2: I've used try catch block to handle error but this errors still crash the application, any way to handle this?
public function callAPI()
{
    $this->accountNumber->set_value('11111111');

    //set shipper postalcode and country code 
    $this->shipper->set_postalCode(12345);
    $this->shipper->set_countryCode('US');
    $this->shipper->set_residential(false);

    //set recipient postalcode and country code 
    $this->recipient->set_postalCode(456789);
    $this->recipient->set_countryCode('US');
    $this->recipient->set_residential(true);

    //set weight and units 
    $this->weight->set_units('LB');
    $this->weight->set_value(26);

    $this->requestedShipment->set_shipper(['address' => $this->shipper]);
    $this->requestedShipment->set_recipient(['address' => $this->recipient]);
    $this->requestedShipment->set_requestedPackageLineItems(array(['weight' => $this->weight]));

    //set pickup type 
    //types: "CONTACT_FEDEX_TO_SCHEDULE", "DROPOFF_AT_FEDEX_LOCATION", "USE_SCHEDULED_PICKUP"
    $this->requestedShipment->set_pickupType("USE_SCHEDULED_PICKUP");

    // set type of rate to be returned 
    //types: "LIST", "INCENTIVE", "ACCOUNT", "PREFERRED" (see documentation for explanations)
    $this->requestedShipment->set_rateRequestType(['ACCOUNT']);

    //set shipment date 
    $this->requestedShipment->set_shipDateStamp("2023-08-17");

    $this->rateRequestControlParameters->set_return_tranist(true);
    $accountNumberJSON = json_encode($this->accountNumber);
    $requestedShipmentJSON = json_encode($this->requestedShipment);

    $url = "https://apis.fedex.com/oauth/token";

    //client id is api key and client secret is secret key
    $data = [
        'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
        'client_id' => 'my_clinet_id',
        'client_secret' => 'my_clinet_secret'
    ];

    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header' => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            'method' => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data)
        )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    $resp = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    $response_data = json_decode($resp);
    $access_token = $response_data->access_token;
    
    //calls function if token is working (token changes every minute)
    if (isset($access_token)) {
        echo $this->get_rates($access_token, $this->accountNumber, $this->requestedShipment, $this->rateRequestControlParameters); 
    }
}

function get_rates($token, $acct, $ship, $rateReqCtrlPara)
{
    $url = "https://apis.fedex.com/rate/v1/rates/quotes";

    $data = ['accountNumber' => $acct, 'requestedShipment' => $ship, 'rateRequestControlParameters' => $rateReqCtrlPara, 'carrierCodes' => array('FDXG') ];
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header' => [
                "Content-type: application/json",
                "Authorization: Bearer {$token}",
                "X-locale: en_US"
            ],
            'method' => 'POST',
            'content' => json_encode($data)
        )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    try{ 
            $resp_data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context); //error here
    }
    catch (exception $e) { echo $e; }
  return $resp_data;
}


file_get_contents does not throw any exceptions, so any attempt to catch one is of course pointless. Add 'ignore_errors' => true to your context options, so that you will get the response body even when the HTTP status code indicated an error - and then check if that contains any more useful information/details about the error. (And why are you even building this using file_get_contents to begin with, instead of using the CURLRequest class?)

The JSON payload shown under https://developer.fedex.com/api/en-us/catalog/rate/v1/docs.html#operation/Rate%20and%20Transit%20times starts with "accountNumber": { "value": "Your account number" }, - is your $acct actually an object with a property named value, or just the plain account number?

@C3roe yes account number is actually an object with value key, and it is working fine and returns the data, but the problem is when I Pass another account number, API gives error . as per my research I assume API works for those accounts which are linked to Fedex API project . just wanted to confirm
